# Get ThreadID of a Thread before it starts

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this pairing mechanism idea that identifies Clients by their ThreadID. When the thread is destroyed, the client's pairing is destroyed and its ID is set to -1.

Now in order for me to get the Thread ID, the thread must of course have been running or started.

I want to know if I can create a thread, get the ID and then set the runnable later on OR if I can get the ID of the current thread that's running my function..

Example of what I want to do:

```
void createClientThreaded(final Client client) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            while(!client.stop()) {
                Utils.sleep(1000);
                //Do other stuff here..

                client.setThreadID(/* This Thread's ID */);

                // Do other stuff here..
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? Also would the Thread ID's be unique per process or unique for the whole system? In other words, can two jar files running at the same time have the same Thread ID?

Comment: Uhh I'm not sure if I did it right but I did: Thread.currentThread().getID(); and that seems to work. However, unable to figure out if it'd be unique per process or system wide.

Comment: This question and answer do not cover how to "Set Thread Runnable Later"

Comment: @MakanTayebi but it covered my need of when the threadID is set. You can delay a thread with a condition variable or lock and set the runnable later. I can show how if you like (I'd post a solution). When I posted this, I wasn't very good at Java and just wanted a way to either set the runnable later OR get the threadID of a thread that hasn't been started yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon. In the meantime i came up with another approach to solve my issue, But I'm just saying. Probably editing the title would be easier.

Comment: @MakanTayebi I added a solution just in case anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread id is immutable, so you won't be able to set it to -1 when the thread terminates.

The id is created as soon as the thread is created, *not* as soon as the thread is started, so you can create the thread, read its id, and start it later.

However, if you're creating and destroying a lot of threads, then you're going to incur a high runtime cost.  It would be more efficient to use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to execute your runnables, however this precludes the option of creating a thread, reading its id, and starting the thread later.  Another option is to create your own class that implements Runnable with a mutable id.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicLong idCounter = new AtomicLong(0);
    private long id;

    public MyRunnable() { this.id = idCounter.getAndIncrement(); }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public long getId() { return this.id; }
    public void run() {}
}
```

Thread ids are per process, not system-wide.  In addition, the process may reuse thread ids (e.g. if the thread with id=5 terminates, then the process may assign id=5 to a new thread).

Answer (score 1):

To run a runnable at some later time:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelayedExecutionThread blocker = new DelayedExecutionThread();
        Thread t = blocker.getThread();
        t.start();

        System.out.println("Thread Started..");
        sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Executing..");

        blocker.setRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("RAN THE THREAD LATER");
            }
        });

        sleep(1);
        System.out.println("Executed..");
    }

    private static class DelayedExecutionThread {
        private Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1, true);
        private Thread thread;
        private Runnable target;

        public DelayedExecutionThread() {
            this.lock.acquireUninterruptibly();

            this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DelayedExecutionThread.this.lock.acquireUninterruptibly();
                    DelayedExecutionThread.this.lock.release();
                    DelayedExecutionThread.this.lock = null;

                    if (DelayedExecutionThread.this.target != null) {
                        DelayedExecutionThread.this.target.run();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public Thread getThread() {
            return this.thread;
        }

        public void setRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
            this.lock.release();
            this.target = runnable;
        }
    }

    private static void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I used a semaphore. You just need some sort of locking or condition. When the thread is started, it attempts to acquire the lock which causes it to "wait" until it can acquire it. When you set the runnable at some later point in time, it will release the lock causing the thread to acquire it, release it, and continue execution.